# Advantage of TRUE() function

Tags: excel, performance, if-statement

doing some excel and file is getting huge and hence performanece goes down.
That got me wondering. I got plenty of **if functions** outputting **"YES"** or **"NO"**. 
I know there is possibility to use if with **TRUE()** function instead, but is it really a **benefit in terms of performance?**

Thanks

Comment: Yes and more so if you save as xlsb. With that said, I'm sure there are better ways to improve the workbook.

Comment: Why not try it, and measure the difference?